# How can I turn off YouTube control with the pause button and make it control the Music app?

Tags: keyboard, catalina, apple-music

I've just noticed that the pause button ( on F8) and forwards/backwards (on F7/F9) buttons on my Mac laptop don't work to control the Music app anymore. Before I updated, I could pause and play my music and I guess movies (in iTunes) from anywhere; now the pause button controls YouTube and maybe other sites (in Safari but not Firefox), and the forwards/backwards buttons don't do anything.

I can't/don't use this feature; I don't use Safari or YouTube really ever, so it is effectively just removal of a pretty nice feature that I liked to use.

**Is there a way to switch the buttons back to make them control the iTunes replacement app/apps?**

I'm Catalina 10.15; I don't think it was a problem until I got Catalina, but I'm bad about updating. I'm on an early 2016 Macbook.

Comment: What were you running before?  I think it was High Sierra that changed the media control keys from always controlling iTunes to controlling the foreground application.

Comment: @MarcWilson I was running Mojave (but I don't listen to music super frequently on my computer, so I guess I didn't notice). Also, it doesn't control the foreground app; it still controls YouTube in Safari when the focus is on other apps.

Comment: I don't use an Apple keyboard, so media control keys aren't an issue for me.  There are utilities out there that claim to restore the original behavior, couldn't tell you the name of one as I've ever bothered with them.

Comment: @MarcWilson So both comments not very useful unfortunately.

Comment: @Stormblessed have you maybe figure out how?